# How to extend ext3 filesystem without lvm?

Tags: partitioning, mount, lvm, ext3

There are some informations of my system. My disk has 59.7GB. I have already used 28GB. It remains about 30GB. Now, I want to add this 30GB to /dev/mmcblk1p1 which's mountpoint is /. I have already tried to use growpart, but it failed. Is it any way to expand it?

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 1]

Answer (score 2):

The steps to resolve this are as follows:

1. Backup any data that you cannot afford to lose.
2. You need to run GParted in a live environment. One way to do this is to create the installation media for Ubuntu and set your machine to boot from it. When it boots select “Try Ubuntu”.
3. In the live environment run GParted. You will probably see your 3 partitions to the left of the graphical representation of the drive and some unallocated space to the right. What ever you see you need to get the unallocated space next to the root partition mmcblklp1.
4. Assuming the unallocated space is to the right proceed as follows. Move mmcblklp3 all the way to the right and click apply. This will take some time, don’t be tempted to interrupt it.
5. Move mmcblklp2 all the way to the right next to mmcblklp3 and click apply. The unallocated space should now be next to mmcblklp1.
6. Expand mmcblklp1 to use all the remaining unallocated space and click apply.
7. Shutdown, set your machine to boot normally and you should have the extra space available in root

Good luck